# Postais com imagem de fundo e texto dinâmico em php, para envio por email

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter

Boa tarde,

Vou precisar fazer uma página web em que um utilizador escolhe uma imagem de fundo e depois numa caixa de texto adiciona um texto e por fim pode enviar por email. Tipo postal de natal de aniversário etc. Alguém me sabe dizer algum tutorial com a melhor maneira de fazer isso? eu tenho feito um mas dá muitos problemas de formatação e por exemplo no gmail nada aparece

Agradeço a ajuda

Comment: Adicione conteúdo a sua pergunta, o que já tentou, códigos, partes, algo que ajude a te ajudar .

Comment: Você pode tentar gerar uma imagem sólida com a Biblioteca GD do PHP.